# Receive class type and argument and return instance

Tags: java, class, generics

I know this maybe be a duplicate but i've been scouring through stack overflow but i'm still yet to find an answer.

What i want to do is accept a `class` type as argument and `return` an `instance` of that class. Here is what i'm trying to do

```java
class A {

}

class B {

    /* 
    * Takes class type as argument and returns an instance of that class
    */
    public static Object createInstanceOfAnyClass(Class<?> klassType) {
        return new klassType();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = B.createInstanceOfAnyClass(A);  // pass class(type) A and receive an instance of A
    }
}
```

Basically, after passing `Class<A>` as argument to `B.createInstanceOfAnyClass`, i should get an instance of `class` `A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a generic type parameter for the return type so you don't need to cast the result from `Object`.

`.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()` can be used on a `Class` object to create an instance using the no-argument constructor.

```java
public static <T> T createInstanceOfAnyClass(Class<T> klassType) {
    try {
        return klassType.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e); // or other handling
    }
}
// Usage:
A a = B.createInstanceOfAnyClass(A.class);
```

Comment: awesome, that works, what if i want to pass argument to the constructor, is that possible?

Comment: @DanielAfriyie You would need to use `.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class)` for example to get the constructor accepting a single String. You can pass as many classes to `.getDeclaredConstructor` as needed. Then pass those arguments to `.newInstance`.